# MySQL Workbench does not open on Windows 8

Tags: mysql-workbench

When i open it, it appears in the Task Manager (but only there, it doesn't actually open) for a couple of seconds and then disappears.

It's version `8.0.18`, and i have `Microsoft .NET Framework 4.6` and `Visual C++ Redistributable for Visual Studio 2015` installed.

What could be the issue?

Comment: Did you try completely reinstalling? (Remove everything by uninstalling and then installing again)

Comment: Yup, tried that.. didn't work.

Comment: You can try 6.3.10 version: https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/

Comment: @dkb, i did try, didn't work :/

Answer (score 0):

MySQ Workbench requires Windows 10 to work. See also the [platform page](https://www.mysql.com/support/supportedplatforms/workbench.html) for this product.